# How can I get the Tweeter in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing New Leaf, I searched and searched, but I found no tweeter! Am I supposed to invite friends to my town? Or am I supposed to earn it?

Comment: Just so you know, The tweeter isabelle gives you is only available in the EU version.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121687/how-are-streetpass-items-rewarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Tweeter)

> It is obtained from visitors in the Happy Home Showcase you have streetpassed 9 or 10 times.
>
> It can also be obtained one from Isabelle at the New Year's Eve countdown if the player speaks to her twice.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Animal Crossing Wikia [Tweeter page](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Tweeter), you're supposed to Streetpass™ a single person ten times to get it.

From the [AC3Wiki](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Happy+Home+Showcase):

- First time: Nothing
- Second time: balloon
- Third time: balloon
- Fourth time: pinwheel
- Fifth time: bunny balloon
- Sixth time: bubble wand
- Seventh time: heart balloon
- Eighth time: ice cream
- Ninth time: soft-serve ice cream
- Tenth time: tweeter
- More than ten times: Random item listed above

You will have to go to the plaza and talk to the person you Streetpassed™.
Supposedly, they will be holding your prize and they will give it to you after speaking with them.

Alternatively, if you talk to Isabelle twice on New Year, she'll give you one.

Comment: Not quite - you need to Streetpass *the same person* 10 times, not 10 different people

Comment: Are you sure? I did read that on one of the wikis, but on a few other sites it said to Streetpass 10 different people. EDIT: You were right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You get the tweeter through streetpass in your happy homes showcase. The tenth time you get someone, a copy of them will be standing in the front with a tweeter, and when you talk to them, they will hand it to you.

Answer (score -1):

In order to receive the tweeter,you have to invite the same person 10 times.Then,you have to talk to that certain person and they will give you the tweeter.

Comment: You have to streetpass them, not invite them.